# Best Practices in Pandas while importing huge datasets from external sources (using SQL)

Tags: sql, python-3.x, pandas

I'm relatively very new to Pandas, and I'm interested in knowing if there's any proven or a better practice that is considered when importing huge (10M+) dataset into dataframes or how are such things done generally? Or is it completely okay to import as big set of data from SQL to pandas directly?

Say for example, I want to query my DB and fetch 10M rec and store it as dataframes. In this case the variable 'query' stores the result set of 10M recs returned from the DB, how safe is it in pandas to get such things done, especially if we are using the 'query' for more computations or are there other alternatives available?

```
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc
import sqlalchemy

#this query gets back with 10M rec
query= pd.read_sql_query(" select * from db", conn)
```

Answer (score 0):

Pandas is built to deal with 'large' data but not so much 'Big' data. However you can use the 'chunk size' parameter, in the loop you could include and preprocessing functions you might have:

```
df_list = []

sql = "SELECT * FROM table"
for chunk in pd.read_sql_query(sql, engine, chunksize=10000):
    chunk_prep = preprocessing(chunk)
    df_list.append(chunk_prep)

df = pd.concat(df_list, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: thanks for your help. so your code basically divides the sql set into '10000' chunks and stores it in to lists. If that's the case, then there will be 100 chunks of the data?

Comment: Yeah, essentially 100 chunks (or data frames) that you can process separately to avoid running out of memory.

Comment: how to access these chunks or blocks of data, say for ex i want to access all the recs between 100-700, at that time...should we compare chunks and get the results?